# Far away objects overlap near ones. Why is that and how can I fix it?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl

Here's what the output looks like:
[image: Screenshot of objects overlapping]

My code is this:

```
(...)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glTranslatef(-10,0,0);
glRotatef(-17.14f,0,1,0);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
for(int i=1;i<=21;i++){
    glTranslatef(10,0,0);
    glRotatef(17.14f,0,1,0);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);glVertex3f(-BOX_SIZE / 2, -BOX_SIZE / 2, BOX_SIZE / 2);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);glVertex3f(BOX_SIZE / 2, -BOX_SIZE / 2, BOX_SIZE / 2);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);glVertex3f(BOX_SIZE / 2, BOX_SIZE / 2, BOX_SIZE / 2);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);glVertex3f(-BOX_SIZE / 2, BOX_SIZE / 2, BOX_SIZE / 2);
    glEnd();

}
(...)
```

It is basically a rotating disk of images (will change them later on).

Comment: Wow, the output looks like a Escher drawing D:

Comment: I am *not* clicking a link with 4chan in the name at work.

Comment: @Kornel Kisielewicz It's the only place I could upload an image without logging in :)

Comment: @BoBTFish I inlined the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable [depth buffering](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/depthbuffer.htm).